# how search word in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day.

Code:

```
column name have rows:

about word test plus
about word tests plus
about word test plus
about word tests plus
about wordtest plus
about wordtests plus
about word testplus
about word testsplus
about wordtestplus
about wordtestsplus
```

i have sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE text LIKE 'test' OR text LIKE 'tests'
```

***Tell me please, how select only rows when exist only full words test or tests?***

P.S. in my example me need get rows:

```
about word test plus
about word tests plus
about word test plus
about word tests plus
```

Comment: Add spaces in your query? `WHERE text LIKE '% test %'`

Comment: you **space** and **%** with test(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this query to receive desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name LIKE '% test %' OR name LIKE '% tests %';
```

Comment: This method will not pick up data which is at starting or ending position. See my code for correct method

Comment: I agree with you [Madhivanan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/358538/madhivanan), but I used data which was in the example. I don't know if he will have 'test/s' as starting word.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ' '+text+' ' LIKE '% test %' OR ' '+text+' ' LIKE '% tests %'
```

Comment: I think `text` is the column name in this example

Comment: Yes it is a column name. You need to append space to get first or last string